# Issue of Beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm a beginner of Python. I would like to scrape those information such as Name, Constituency, Education and professional qualifications, Occupation, Political affiliation, Office address, Office telephone and E-mail from this website:
https://www.legco.gov.hk/general/english/members/yr16-20/lky.htm

However, i just only scrape the name on this website. How can i finish the requirements? Here is my coding:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.legco.gov.hk/general/chinese/members/yr16-20/biographies.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
for anchor in soup.find_all('a'):
    href = anchor.get('href', '/')
    if href.startswith("lky"):
      href = "https://www.legco.gov.hk/general/english/members/yr16-20/" + href
      print(href)
      r2 = requests.get(href)
      #print(r2.text)
      detail_soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text,'html.parser')
      name = detail_soup.find("h2")
      print(name.text.strip())
      break
print("End of loop")
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: likely you're to learn Python (in general) & BeautifulSoup (in particular) to understand what and how you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.

Your error was that you did not try to retrieve certain elements with

```
details.find_all
```

So please check my code for your reference and study BeautfiulSoup documentation for your progress.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.legco.gov.hk/general/chinese/members/yr16-20/biographies.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
for anchor in soup.find_all('a'):
    href = anchor.get('href', '/')
    if href.startswith("lky"):
      href = "https://www.legco.gov.hk/general/english/members/yr16-20/" + href
      print(href)
      r2 = requests.get(href)

      #get name
      detail_soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text,'html.parser')
      name = detail_soup.find("h2")
      name = name.text.strip()
      print("Name:", name, "\n")

      #find headers
      strong = detail_soup.find_all('strong')
      heads = []
      for i in strong:
             heads.append(i.text.strip())
      print('Headers:\n',heads)

      #find header childs
      data_details = []
      details = detail_soup.find_all('li')
      for i in details:
          data_details.append(i.text.strip())
      print('\nDetails:\n', data_details)

      #table parsing
      div = detail_soup.find('div',{'id':'container'})
      table = div.find('table')
      data = []
      rows = table.find_all('tr')
      for row in rows:
          cols = row.find_all('td')
          cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
          data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

      print("\nTable data:\n",data)
```

Output:

```
https://www.legco.gov.hk/general/english/members/yr16-20/lky.htm
Name: Hon Andrew LEUNG Kwan-yuen, GBS, JP

Headers:
 ['Constituency :', 
'Education and professional qualifications :',
 'Occupation :', 'Political affiliation :', 'Office address', ':', 'Office telephone', ':', 'Office fax', ':', 'E-mail', ':', 'Website', ':']

Details:
 ['Functional Constituency - Industrial (First)', 
'BSc (Hon), Leeds University', 'Fellow, Textiles Institute', 
'Fellow, Clothing and Footwear Institute',
 'Honorary Doctor of Business Administration, 
Coventry University, UK', 'Merchant', 'Business and Professionals Alliance for Hong Kong']

Table data:
 [['Office address', ':', 'Room 710,
 Legislative Council Complex,\r\n1 Legislative Council Road,
 Central, Hong Kong'], ['Office telephone', ':', '2537 1339'],
 ['Office fax', ':', '2697 8482'],
 ['E-mail', ':', 'andrewleunglegco@outlook.com'],
 ['Website', ':', '-']]
```

Answer (score 0):

A general good habit when scraping is to go from close to closer. First and foremost you open the browser and inspect the region you're trying to scrape.

We can see that the whole content is found in the `<div id="_content_new_" class="members-word">` tag. So scrape for that first:

```py
root_div = soup.find('div', {'class': '_content_new_'})
```

Next we want to find the URLs to each member. Upon further inspection we can see that the links are found in the `<div class="bio-member-info">` tag

```py
member_divs = root_div.findAll('div', {'class': 'bio-member-info'})
```

Now what we need from each `div` is the `href` attribute from `<a>` tags.

```py
links = [div.find('a')['href'] for div in member_divs]
```

Now all we have to do is to access each member's page individually and scrape the info.

When inspecting an individual page we notice the following:

- all of the info is enclosed in the `<div id="_content_" class="content_word">` tag.
- the name is enclosed in a `<h2>` tag
- the constituency in enclosed in the **first** `<ul>` tag
- the "Education and professional qualifications" are enclosed in the **second** `<ul>` tag and there can multiple `<li>` tags
- *so on so forth*

```py
# We need the full URLs
base_url = 'https://www.legco.gov.hk/general/chinese/members/yr16-20/'

# We get the members' pages first
urls = list(map(lambda href: base_url + href, links))

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)                            # We request the HTML page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')      # Apply BS
    main_div = soup.find('div', {'id': '_content_'}) # Get the container div 

    # Scrape each information needed
    name = soup.findAll('h2')[0].getText()
    constituency = soup.findAll('ul')[0].find('li').getText()  # We need the first <ul>
    education = soup.findAll('ul')[1].findAll('li')            # We need the second <ul>
    education = [li.getText() for li in education]

    # Continue for all the remaining info
```

That should scrape the information for all members. Hope this helped!